# Get location using json and tweepy?

Tags: python, mysql, json, tweepy

This is my code. when i run this code i get an error 
**raise exception
TypeError: string indices must be integers**

```
    from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import MySQLdb
import simplejson
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            passwd='',
            db='python', 
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True      
            )
cursor=db.cursor()

ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = simplejson.loads(HTMLParser().unescape(data))
        #all_data = simplejson.loads(data)

        # check to ensure there is text in 
        # the json data
        if 'text' in all_data:
          tweet = all_data["text"]
          username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
```

**i add this statement to get location but this doesnot work**

```
         place= data['place']['full_name']
         #location1= all_data["location"]

          cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO tweeter (time, username, tweet,location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
            (time.time(), username, tweet,place))
          db.commit()
          print((username,tweet))
          return True
        else:
          return True
```

**this def on_status function is added by me after taking some help from internet**

```
       def on_status(self, status):
    if status.place:
        print 'place:', status.place.full_name
        return True
on_event = on_status
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream (auth ,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["Earthquake"],languages = ["en"], stall_warnings = True )
```

DO help me to resolve my problem. Thank you

Comment: Do you know on which line the error is being thrown?

Comment: i think on place=data["place"]["fullname]
  def on_status(self, status):
    if status.place:
        print 'place:', status.place.full_name
        return True
on_event = on_status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before that you have to create a table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tweeter (time DATE,username VARCHAR(20),tweet VARCHAR(200),location VARCHAR(100));
```

Then run the script:

```
import tweepy
import MySQLdb


conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            passwd='',
            db='python',
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True
            )
x = conn.cursor()


consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()


    def on_status(self, status):

        print status.text,'\n'
        print status.user.screen_name, "\n"
        print status.created_at, "\n"
        if status.place:
            print status.place.full_name
            x.execute(
            "INSERT INTO tweeter (time, username, tweet,location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
            (status.created_at, status.user.screen_name, status.text,status.place.full_name))
            conn.commit()

        else:
            x.execute(
            "INSERT INTO tweeter (time, username, tweet,location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
            (status.created_at, status.user.screen_name, status.text,"None"))
            conn.commit()


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(track=["earthquake"])
```